# Keep a variable in scope within _.forEach() that is not array being looped over

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach, lodash

I have a separate array that occasionally I need to push objects into based on the content of the looped array:

```
let x: any[];
_.forEach(blocks, (block:any) => {
    // some code that does not matter...
    x.push(block.some.property);
});
```

The documentation says that Lodash's forEach() only passes in 3 arguments; the value, an index, and a collection (assuming this is the initial array/iterable).

Is there a way to force x into scope within the forEach()? Declaring it `var` just gets a runtime error when it hits x.push(). I've mostly solved the problem with another approach entirely, but it's irritating that there's no way to insist.

Comment: ...like any function, in the `_.forEach()` callback you're able to use variables from all enclosing scopes. What error are you getting?

Comment: Any specific reason you’re using lodash instead of the built-in Array.forEach method?

Comment: @rhys_stubbs Maintaining someone else's code, trying to conform to my employer's coding conventions. I've solved the original problem, but I do want to understand this better in case I come up with another problem that is similar... they're big lodash believers here.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the x variable

```
let x: any[]=[];
```

Most probably it is throwing this error to you
[image]